# How to update text element after property change in Polymer 3?

Tags: data-binding, polymer, polymer-3.x

So I'm using a data table which has an active element. When that active elment changes I store the name of the active element in a property of my polymer element. Then I display this String property in a div. 
Now I know for certain that the property change works, because I console.log it after a change, the div displaying the property doesn't update and continually displays the default value I have set.

```
export class ProjectsOverview extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
      return html`
         ...
         <div>{{currentProject}}</div>
         ...
      `
  }

  static get properties() {
      return {
        currentProject: {
          type: String,
          value: "placeholder",
          notify: true,
          reflectToAttribute: true
        }
      };
  }

  connectedCallback() {
      super.connectedCallback();

      const grid = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('vaadin-grid');

      grid.addEventListener('active-item-changed', function(event) {
        const item = event.detail.value;

        grid.selectedItems = [item];
        if (item) {
          this.set('currentProject', item.name);
        } else {
          this.set('currentProject', '');
        }
        console.log(this.currentProject);
      });
  }
}
```

My expected result would be that every time the currentProject property is updated, the div displaying the property updates as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `active-item-changed` callback does not have its context bound to the Polymer instance (i.e., `this` is the grid and not the Polymer component). Instead of the function expression, use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to automatically bind `this` to the correct context.

```js
// grid.addEventListener('active-item-changed', function(event) { // DON'T DO THIS
grid.addEventListener('active-item-changed', (event) => {
  /* this is the Polymer instance here */
  this.set('currentProject', ...);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Your scope is wrong. You're using an anonymous function so when you try to set `currentProject`, you do that when your `this` is your anonymous function. Use `.bind(this)` to fix your problem.

---

```
grid.addEventListener('active-item-changed', function(event) {
        const item = event.detail.value;

        grid.selectedItems = [item];
        if (item) {
          this.set('currentProject', item.name);
        } else {
          this.set('currentProject', '');
        }
        console.log(this.currentProject);
      }.bind(this));
```